# How to unit test enum composed via @JsonCreator?

Tags: java, json, junit, jackson

I am using [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind) to deserialize a JSON string into an enum.

```
public enum RoomType {

    SHARED("shared"),
    PRIVATE("private");

    private String value;

    RoomType(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public static RoomType fromJson(final String jsonValue) {
        for (RoomType type : values()) {
            if (type.value.equals(jsonValue)) {
                return type;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @JsonValue
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return value;
    }

}
```

I want to unit test the different edge cases:

```
@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
public class RoomTypeTest {

    private final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Test
    public void fromJsonWithShared() throws Exception {
        String json = "{\"roomType\":\"shared\"}";
        RoomType type = mapper.readValue(json, RoomType.class);
        assertThat(type).isEqualTo(RoomType.SHARED);
    }

}
```

The test **fails**. When I debug I see that `jsonValue` is `null` when `RoomType.fromJson` is invoked. Seems like that Jackson does not pick up the value from the JSON string.

#### Related examples

- [EnumCreatorTest929.java](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/8ccb1ea999b8ae4ce52354033f9ec82028969545/src/test/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/failing/EnumCreatorTest929.java)

Comment: Your unittest does what is should: it shows your code is wrong at `if (type.value.equals(jsonValue)) `...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Jackson doesn't know what value to pass to that `fromJson` method. Try adding @JsonProperty:

```
@JsonCreator
public static RoomType fromJson(@JsonProperty("roomType") final String jsonValue) {
     ....
}
```

Comment: Tests work now. (Strange, because I tried that before and it failed. It seems Android Studio was caching something.) Thank you.

Comment: Haven't used Android Studio but I doubt it would cache something. IDEs are basically just text editors. Maybe the class wasn't compiled autmaticaly or something... It happens...